# WMI query to select disk containing system volume

Tags: wmi, wmi-query

I need to get some information (model and serial) of the disk that contains the system volume (usually C:). I'm using this query:

```
SELECT * FROM Win32_DiskDrive WHERE Index=0
```

My question is, is the disk with Index=0 always the disk containing the system volume?

**Edit:** I added an additional query to get the index of the disk containing the boot partition:

```
SELECT * FROM Win32_DiskPartition WHERE BootPartition=True
```

Then the original query changes to

```
SELECT * FROM Win32_DiskDrive WHERE Index={diskIndex}
```

I figured I'd be pretty safe this way. Suggestions for better solutions are always welcome :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My question is, is the disk with Index=0 always the disk containing the system volume?

In my case the answer is **`No`**. My system disk has index 1.
Also your assumption that the system disk is always bootable is incorrect.

```
$ wmic os get "SystemDrive"
SystemDrive
C:
```

```
$ wmic logicaldisk where 'DeviceID="C:"' assoc /resultclass:Win32_DiskPartition

...\\DZEN\ROOT\CIMV2:Win32_DiskPartition.DeviceID="Disk #1, Partition #0"...
```

```
wmic diskdrive where 'Index=1' get "Caption"
Caption
OCZ-VERTEX4 // Yes, this is my system disk.
```

Also your assumpion about `BootPartition` usage is incorrect for cases when bootmanager is on another disk, like in my case:

```
wmic partition where 'DeviceID like "Disk_#1%"' get DeviceID,BootPartition
BootPartition  DeviceID
FALSE          Disk #1, Partition #0

wmic partition where 'BootPartition="TRUE"' get DeviceID,BootPartition
BootPartition  DeviceID
TRUE           Disk #4, Partition #0
TRUE           Disk #3, Partition #0
```

As you can see, nor the system disk neither one of bootable ones do not have Index=0 for my case. Actually I have Index=0 for the one of non system and non bootable disk.

Answer (score 1):

As stated, add an extra query to get the index of the disk containing the boot partition:

```
{diskIndex} = SELECT * FROM Win32_DiskPartition WHERE BootPartition=True
SELECT * FROM Win32_DiskDrive WHERE Index={diskIndex}
```

Unfortunatly WMI doesn't seem to support JOINs, which would have made the query a little more efficient.